# C# Date Parse Exact Issue

Tags: c#, datetime

The following code produces an error, any ideas why?

```
string dateFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string properDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString() , dateFormatString , null ).ToString()
```

Error is: String is not recognised as a valid date and time.

Comment: are you sure the ToString() of datetime comes out exactly like shown in the format mask?

Comment: You know... if it worked, it would be identical to: DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: err..no, it wouldn't. See answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Now.ToString()` formats the date using the current culture. You need to specify the same format: `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")` that's expected by the ParseExact function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this - rest is piece of cake.
http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/msnet-formatting-strings.pdf

and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

Comment: very useful indeed, thanks for posting, good reference material, but doesn't quite solve my problem.

Comment: Hi JL - only thing here to be noted is whatever you are passing should be in the format you are trying to parse back - you are sending a default string representation of date time which isnt same as "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" but instead it is "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" slash and dot difference that is.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
string dateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string properDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormatString);
```

EDIT: According to your comments, you are trying to match the format to that common in the Czech Republic. You should use `CultureInfo` to do do that:

```
string properDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("cs-CZ"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your local culture write dates as "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss" ? Simply: if the date's `ToString()` doesn't produce this layout, then it won't parse cleanly - and `ParseExact` is **not** very forgiving.

I'm wondering if you actually want to call:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```