# C# Parsing Dates and Times

Tags: c#

I have some code in app along the lines of

```
DateTime activityDate = DateTime.Parse(tempDate + " " + tempTime);
```

Where *tempDate* is a string with values such as "2009-12-01" ( i.e. yyyy-mm-dd )
and *tempTime* is a string with values such as "23:12:10" ( i.e. hh:mm:ss )

Firstly, is there a better way to combine these to get a DateTime, and secondly is the code above safe to work in any region ( if not is there a way to handle this )

Hmm looking at the date more closely the concatenated date & time is actually in this format "2009-11-26T19:37:56+00:00" - what's the format string for the timezone part of the date/time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the format is guaranteed, `ParseExact` may be safer (sepcifying the pattern):

```
DateTime activityDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tempDate + " " + tempTime,
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: If I had timezone information in the string, what would the pattern be
(i.e. 2009-11-26T19:37:56+00:00)

Comment: For that pattern, I'd use `XmlConvert.ToDateTime(s)`, which handles this format directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to specify the date and time format.

e.g.:

```
DateTime dateTime = 
        DateTime.ParseExact("2009-12-01 23:12:10", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Which yields:

```
Assert.That(dateTime, Is.EqualTo(new DateTime(2009, 12, 1, 23, 12, 10)));
```

You can also specify the culture that uses this format and parse using it the date and time while keeping the parsing safe from the processing OS culture.
From a quick look it seems that there is no culture with this exact predefined format, but in general many standard formats exists in the framework cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Use ParseExact. It's been asked a few times on SO.. [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437078/c-date-parse-exact-mindate-issues), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740983/c-date-parse-exact-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ParseExact to specify a format for the parsing. That way there is no risk for it to be parsed in any other way:

```
DateTime activityDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tempDate + " " + tempTime, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

As if you cared, another option would be to do:

```
DateTime activityDateOnly =
    DateTime.ParseExact(tempDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

TimeSpan activityTime =
    TimeSpan.ParseExact(tempTime, "hh':'mm':'ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime activityDate = activityDateOnly + activityTime;
```

Just an option...